# Bulk Rename from list of file names

Tags: batch, window, rename

I have a list of random file names. I want to use this list to rename all files in a particular folder.

The folder contains the files:

```
Mike.exe
Josh.exe
```

I want them to be renamed using names from a `list.txt`

```
Mike.exe -> Mickey.exe
```

Like this. What Windows BAT script or tool can do this?

Content of `Name.list` looks like:

```
Lorem Ipsum
Foo Bar
Baz Yak
```

And The `file.list` looks like:

```
Skype(1)
Skype(2)
```

All files are exe's.

Comment: How exactly should the content of list.txt look like?

Comment: If you have a list.txt with lines of the Format "Mike.exe Mickey.exe", then just prepend a "ren " to each line, rename the file as list.bat and run it.

Comment: @FsMaxB 1 Name per line

Comment: So you actually have two lists? Or do you want to rename the files in a folder in  alphabetical order, so the first file alphabetically gets the first filename in the list?

Comment: I have one folder with random files. And one list with Random names. I need to use this list name to rename file in folder. Order doesn't matter. Just need then to be renamed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Flash Renamer](http://www.rlvision.com/flashren/) (shareware, but free to use) can accomplish this. Suppose you have five files in a folder: `1.txt`, `2.txt`, `3.txt`, `4.txt`, and `5.txt`. You'll then want a CSV file containing your rename rules, looking something like this:

```
1,One
2,Two
3,Three
4,Four
5,Five
```

(The program is flexible with the choice of delimiter and which columns contain the find and replace strings, however, so that format is not a hard and fast requirement.) See [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErB0f.jpg) for a demonstration -- navigate to the folder containing your files (the third icon in the toolbar above the explorer), specify the CSV file containing your rules on the left, then click Rename on the bottom.